# Run an exe file and insert some input to it with java

Tags: java

I have problem in running an exe file with java.
exe file process is like this : after run a command it ask for 
password and when i insert password it does the job.
but in my java program I trying to run some commands with an exe file.
i invoke exe file an run my first command and after that i insert password with outputstream but t console get freez and it does nothing.
my code:

```
    String command = "xxxx";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    writer.write("123456");
    writer.close();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));


    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

// read the output from the command
        String s = null;
        System.out.println("output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
// read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println(" error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

[image: output]

Comment: You should read the command's output and stderr in two distinct threads. Also, use `p.waitFor()` to wait for the process to finish.

Comment: @ammoQ how can i read them in two distinct thread?

Comment: Here is an example: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO07-J.+Do+not+let+external+processes+block+on+IO+buffers (last example on that page)